# Is there any method that i can show a "Insufficient TOKEN balance" in metamask?

Tags: metamask, ethereumjs

for example:

I want to buy a blind box, using a ERC-20 token.

Is there any method that i can show **My TOKEN Is Not Enough** in **metamask**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean in your codebase? You can add `require(_priceOfBlindBox>msg.value, "Insufficient token balance" in Wallet");` - then on the frontend you can display this error as needed. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the frontend from where the blind box is bought you can intersept the transaction's response and display what ever message you want but if you are not you can't.